# "A view on" vs "a view of"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the difference, if any, between the meaning of "a view on" and "a view of"?

Example:

> a new view of environmentalism

vs.

> A new view on Environmentalism

Both can be found with more or less frequency on the web, and the same on [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20view%20to%2Ca%20view%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20view%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20view%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: For all practical purposes ***of*** and ***on*** are equivalent and interchangeable here, but [***of*** is far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=view+on+the+matter%2Cview+of+the+matter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cview%20on%20the%20matter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cview%20of%20the%20matter%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I don't understand how ngram works. If you actually click on the example results, there are several *more* hits for "view on the matter."

Answer (score 3):

Although not every speaker might recognize or accept these distinctions, I would understand **a view of** to mean "understanding of" or "attitude towards" and **a view on** to mean "opinion with respect to".

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially the same.

---

But if you want to draw some kind of distinction, *of* is used in a more literal sense:

> I have a good view **of** the park from my window.

Meanwhile, *on* is used more figuratively (although *of* can also be used figuratively):

> After the discussion, I have a better view **on** how it works.

Still, for practical purposes they are mostly interchangeable.